# Python imaplib search 'NOT' keyword

Tags: python, imap, imaplib

I've been learning to use the python imaplib library for a project I'm working on,but I'm seeing some behavior that has me stumped. When I try to search with 'NOT FROM' it returns the same as 'FROM', as if the not wasn't even there. My assumption is that I am just putting the command in wrong, but I've searched for a few examples and every one I have found seems to do it the way I am.

```
import imaplib
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host)
mail.login(email, pw)
mail.select(mailbox)
# The following two work as expeceted
# and give different results
mail.uid('search', None, '(NOT NEW)')
mail.uid('search', None, '(NEW)')
# However the following two give the same
mail.uid('search', None, '(FROM gmail)')
mail.uid('search', None, '(NOT FROM gmail)')
```

I've tried every way of inputing it I can think of, but none of them seem to work. I've checked both RFC2060, the one imaplib says it is based on and some of the more recent ones.

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.5+
```

Does anyone see where I am messing up or is also seeing this issue? There is very little out there about this particular library it seems

---

EDIT:
I've looked in to this a little further and it appears to be a problem specifically with the  imap server I am connecting to.. After trying to connect over openssl with

```
$ openssl s_client -connect imap.mail.yahoo.com:993 -crlf
```

and logging in and trying

```
UID SEARCH FROM "gmail"
UID SEARCH NOT FROM "gmail"
```

I get the same behavior.

However when I connect to a gmail account

```
$ openssl s_client -connect imap.gmail.com:993 -crlf
```

and try

```
UID SEARCH FROM "gmail"
UID SEARCH NOT FROM "gmail"
```

I get the expected behavior.

I guess this is "SOLVED" then

Comment: I checked your code, that works fine.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not sure what you mean by that, I know it runs just fine. The problem was that NOT FROM "foo" was returning the same as FROM "foo". Do you mean that didn't happen for you? (Did you try it on yahoo mail? Because it seems like that was the root of the issue.)

Comment: I tried with Gmail , with NOT FROM 'gmail' it got me : ('OK', ['21 23 24 25 35 37 38 41 42']) and with FROM 'gmail' : ('OK', ['12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 22 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 36'])

Comment: Yep! Worked for me as well with gmail, I checked "capability" for each one and it seems like Yahoo imap doesn't fully support SEARCH while gmail does.

Comment: Does `NOT (FROM "gmail")` work?

Comment: This question is over 2 years old. I haven't checked since then. At that time Yahoo wasn't fully implementing SEARCH. That may have changed; I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked in to this a little further and it appears to be a problem specifically with the imap server I am connecting to.. After trying to connect over openssl with

```
$ openssl s_client -connect imap.mail.yahoo.com:993 -crlf
```

and logging in and trying

```
UID SEARCH FROM "gmail"
UID SEARCH NOT FROM "gmail"
```

I get the same behavior.

However when I connect to a gmail account

```
$ openssl s_client -connect imap.gmail.com:993 -crlf
```

and try

```
UID SEARCH FROM "gmail"
UID SEARCH NOT FROM "gmail"
```

I get the expected behavior.

I guess this is "SOLVED" then

Answer (score 0):

`NOT FROM gmail` works fine in Gmail imap, But about Yahoo it doesn't work.

Try it:

```
import imaplib
## connect to imap server
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.mail.yahoo.com')
mail.login('username','password')
mail.select('inbox')

## search all mails
all_mail = mail.search(None,'ALL')

## search all gmails
all_gmail = mail.search(None,'(FROM "gmail")')

## make them as list of int
all_mail = [x for x in all_mail[1][0].split() if x != ""]
all_gmail = [x for x in all_gmail[1][0].split() if x != ""]
not_gmail = [x for x in all_mail if x not in all_gmail]
#not_gmail = set(all_mail) - set(all_gmail)    

## get the output
print "all mail: " + str(all_mail)
print "all gmail: " + str(all_gmail)
print "all not gmail: " + str(not_gmail)
```

It's a little slow , but works fine.
And for RFC have a look into:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501.html

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-imapext-regex-00

Comment: I came up with a similar hack, but I just make them sets instead because order doesn't really matter to me :)

Kinda silly that yahoo doesn't have SEARCH available in working condition in my opinion!

Comment: @user3591723 I just find this way. hope it be useful for you. ;)